# Graphical representation of limit superior and limit inferior of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider [this image on Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Lim_sup_example_5.png) that attempts to graphically represent the concepts of $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\text{lim sup}} \space a_n$ and $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\text{lim inf}} \space a_n$.

Now, I realize that there is *some* sequence $ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, whose graph for $n \leq 600$ is identical to the one shown on the photo, such that the dashed black lines represent the limit superior and limit inferior of that sequence.

But what if I define $x_n := 0$  for every $n > 600$? Wouldn't the sequence, then, be convergent and make the current depiction of limit superior and limit inferior (as shown on the photo) wrong?

In other words, it seems that when one *only* has this photo, then one cannot determine *precisely* what the limit superior and limit inferior of the sequence are (but only an upper bound and a lower bound for those limits), because one wouldn't know how the sequence is defined for large values of $n$.

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You aren't wrong. The picture comes with the implicit assumption that the sequence continues to "look like that" for larger values of $n$. We cannot plot infinitely many values after all.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence and only the values of $x_n$ for $n\leq m$  are known where $m$ is some fixed positive integer then **nothing** is known about $\limsup x_n$ and $\liminf x_n$.

This is illustrated by the fact that for the sequence $(y_n)_n$ prescribed by $y_n=x_{n+m}$ we have:$$\limsup y_n=\limsup x_n\text{ and }\liminf y_n=\liminf x_n$$

We could say that $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are determined by the "tail" of the sequence.

Comment: But if we do additionally know
$ \underset{n \geq m}{\text{sup}} \space x_n$ and $\underset{n \geq m}{\text{inf}} \space x_n$, then it seems we would have an upper bound and a lower bound, respectively, for the limit superior and limit inferior of the sequence. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.